# Calculating the integral of the Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'd like to find $\int_{A} K dA$ for the surface $S = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2 + y^2 - z^{2/3} = 0, 1 < z < 8\}$

I've had an attempt but I'm fairly certain that this surface is diffeomorphic to a piece of the flat plane so the integral should be $2\pi$.

However, computing directly using the following parametrisation:
$x(r, \theta) = (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), r^3) $

Gives me: $E = 1+9r^4$, $F = 0$, $G = r^2$ for coefficients of the first fundamental form;

$L = \dfrac{6r^2}{(9r^6 + r^2)^{1/2}}$,   $M = 0$, $ N =  \dfrac{3r^4}{(9r^6 + r^2)^{1/2}}$, as coefficients of the 2nd fundamental form, so that:

$$K = \dfrac{18r^6}{(9r^6 + r^2)^2}$$

Then upon integrating:

$\int_A K dA = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2 \dfrac{18r^6}{(9r^6 + r^2)^2} \sqrt{9r^6 + r^2 } dr d\theta $

I really have no idea where I've messed up here. It feels like the method is generally right, but I've just overlooked something. I would greatly appreciate any help spotting where I've messed up in my computation.

Comment: Your parametrization is incorrect: $$ x^2+y^2-z^{3/2} = r^2\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\theta - (r^3)^{3/2} = r^2 - r^{9/2} \not\equiv 0. $$

Comment: The map $(x, y, (x^2+y^2)^{2/3})\mapsto (x, y)$ is indeed a diffeomorphism of $S$ onto the annulus $\{(x, y)\ :\ 1<x^2+y^2<8^{3/2}\}$.

Comment: @MisterRiemann I wrote the question wrong! I'm sorry it should be $z^{2/3}$ I'll edit the question now.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Can you see where my working breaks down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't know why you expect an answer of $2\pi$. If $S$ and $S'$ are diffeomorphic, there's no reason their curvature integrals should match up. You'd need them to be *isometric* to arrive at that conclusion.

The correct formula for the Gaussian curvature is $K=18\dfrac{r^2}{(1+9r^4)^2}$ (which agrees with your formula after algebraic simplification). If you know the formula for Gaussian curvature in an orthogonal parametrization,
$$K=-\frac1{2\sqrt{EG}}\left(\Big(\frac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}\Big)_v+\Big(\frac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}}\Big)_u\right),$$
it's quite easy to compute. But, better yet, you can easily evaluate the integral $\iint_S K\,dA$ in the case (as you have here) where $E$ and $G$ are functions of just one variable, $r$. Note that
\begin{align*}
\iint_S K\,dA &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2 -\frac1{2\sqrt{EG}}\Big(\frac{G_r}{\sqrt{EG}}\Big)_r\sqrt{EG}\,dr\,d\theta \\ &= -\frac12\int_0^{2\pi} \Big(\frac{G_r}{\sqrt{EG}}\Big)\Big]_{r=1}^{r=2}d\theta\\ &= \pi\Big(\frac{G_r}{\sqrt{EG}}\Big)\Big]_{r=2}^{r=1},
\end{align*}
since $G$ is independent of $\theta$.

Comment: Oh! For some reason I was under the impression that two compact surfaces having a diffeomorphism between them will preserve the Euler characteristic. That's why I was expecting a curvature of $2\pi$, because of the global Gauss-Bonnet theorem. Is this not the case?

Comment: If they're compact surfaces without boundary, yes. But here you would need the geodesic curvature integrals on the boundary.